# Hyphenation issues with latex

Tags: xetex, luatex, hyphenation, alignment, indic

I am confused with the alignment of the text. I am not able to reduce space between words so that I can adjust the alignment and give proper hyphenation.

```
\documentclass[two-sided,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[paperheight=8.5in,paperwidth=5.5in,top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in,bindingoffset=0.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=kannada]{kannada} %% or other languages
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\newfontfamily\kannadafont[Script=Kannada,Path=$HOME/Downloads/fonts/kannada/]{Vagisha_1_0_7.ttf}
\newcommand{\zwj}{\char"200D}
\newcommand{\ds}{\char"1CDA}
%\spaceskip=0.6em
%\raggedright
\onehalfspacing
\begin{document}
%\title{॥  ॥}
%\date{}
%\maketitle

\begin{center}
\Large{॥ ಶ್ರೀ ರುದ್ರಪ್ರಶ್ನಃ ॥ }
\end{center}

ಶಂಭ॑ವೇ॒ ನಮಃ॑ ॥ ನಮೋ ಭಗವತೇ॑ ರುದ್ರಾ॒ಯ ॥ ಓಂ ನಮ॑ಸ್ತೇ ರುದ್ರ ಮ॒ನ್ಯವ॑ ಉ॒ತೋತ॒ ಇಷ॑ವೇ॒ ನಮಃ॑ ।
ನಮ॑ಸ್ತೇ ~ಅಸ್ತು॒ ಧನ್ವ॑ನೇ ಬಾ॒ಹುಭ್ಯಾ॑ಮು॒ತ ತೇ॒ ನಮಃ॑ ।
ಯಾ ತ॒ ಇಷುಃ॑ ಶಿ॒ವತ॑ಮಾ ಶಿ॒ವಂ ಬ॒ಭೂವ॑ ತೇ॒ ಧನುಃ॑ ।
ಶಿ॒ವಾ ಶ॑ರ॒ವ್ಯಾ॑ ಯಾ ತವ॒ ತಯಾ॑ ನೋ ರುದ್ರ ಮೃಡಯ ।
ಯಾ ತೇ॑ ರುದ್ರ ಶಿ॒ವಾ ತ॒ನೂರಘೋ॒ರಾಽಪಾ॑ಪಕಾಶಿನೀ । 
ತಯಾ॑ ನಸ್\zwj ತ॒ನುವಾ॒ ಶಂತ॑ಮಯಾ॒ ಗಿರಿ॑ಶಂತಾ॒ಭಿಚಾ॑ಕಶೀಹಿ ।
ಯಾಮಿಷುಂ॑ ಗಿರಿಶಂತ॒ ಹಸ್ತೇ॒ ಬಿಭ॒ರ್ಷ್ಯಸ್ತ॑ವೇ ।
ಶಿ॒ವಾಂ ಗಿ॑ರಿತ್ರ॒ ತಾಂ ಕು॑ರು॒ \!ಮಾ \!ಹಿꣳ॑ಸೀಃ॒ \!ಪುರು॑ಷಂ॒ ಜಗ॑ತ್ ।
ಶಿ॒ವೇನ॒ ವಚ॑ಸಾ ತ್ವಾ॒ ಗಿರಿ॒ಶಾಚ್ಛಾ॑ವದಾಮಸಿ ।
ಯಥಾ॑ ನಃ॒ ಸರ್ವ॒ಮಿಜ್ಜಗ॑ದಯ॒ಕ್ಷ್ಮꣳ ಸು॒ಮನಾ॒ ಅಸ॑ತ್ । 
~ಅಧ್ಯ॑ವೋಚದಧಿವ॒ಕ್ತಾ ~ಪ್ರ॑ಥ॒ಮೋ ದೈವ್ಯೋ॑ ಭಿ॒ಷಕ್ ।
ಅಹೀಗ್॑ಶ್ಚ॒ ಸರ್ವಾಂ᳚ಜಂ॒ಭಯಂ॒ತ್ಸರ್ವಾ᳚ಶ್ಚ ಯಾತುಧಾ॒ನ್ಯಃ॑ ।
ಅ॒ಸೌ ಯಸ್ತಾ॒ಮ್ರೋ ಅ॑ರು॒ಣ ಉ॒ತ ಬ॒ಭ್ರುಃ ಸು॑ಮಂ॒ಗಲಃ॑ ।
ಯೇ ಚೇ॒ಮಾꣳ ರು॒ದ್ರಾ ಅ॒ಭಿತೋ॑ ದಿ॒ಕ್ಷು ಶ್ರಿ॒ತಾಃ ಸ॑ಹಸ್ರ॒ಶೋಽವೈ॑ಷಾ॒ꣳ॒ ಹೇಡ॑ ಈಮಹೇ ।  
ಅ॒ಸೌ ಯೋ॑ಽವ॒ಸರ್ಪ॑ತಿ॒ ನೀಲ॑ಗ್ರೀವೋ॒ ವಿಲೋ॑ಹಿತಃ ।
ಉ॒ತೈನಂ॑ ಗೋ॒ಪಾ ಅ॑ದೃಶ॒ನ್ನದೃ॑ಶನ್ನುದಹಾ॒ರ್ಯಃ॑ ।
ಉ॒ತೈನಂ॒ ವಿಶ್ವಾ॑ ಭೂ॒ತಾನಿ॒ ಸ ದೃ॒ಷ್ಟೋ ಮೃ॑ಡಯಾತಿ ನಃ ।
ನಮೋ॑ ಅಸ್ತು॒ ನೀಲ॑ಗ್ರೀವಾಯ ಸಹಸ್ರಾ॒ಕ್ಷಾಯ॑ ಮೀ॒ಢುಷೇ᳚ ।
ಅಥೋ॒ ಯೇ ಅ॑ಸ್ಯ॒ ಸತ್ತ್ವಾ॑ನೋ॒ಽಹಂ ತೇಭ್ಯೋ॑ಽಕರ॒ನ್ನಮಃ॑ ।
ಪ್ರಮುಂ॑ಚ॒ ಧನ್ವ॑ನ॒ಸ್ತ್ವಮು॒ಭಯೋ॒ರಾರ್ತ್ನಿ॑ಯೋ॒ರ್ಜ್ಯಾಂ । 
ಯಾಶ್ಚ॑ ತೇ॒ ಹಸ್ತ॒ ಇಷ॑ವಃ॒ ಪರಾ॒ ತಾ ಭ॑ಗವೋ ವಪ ।
ಅ॒ವ॒ತತ್ಯ॒ ಧನು॒ಸ್ತವꣳ ಸಹ॑ಸ್ರಾಕ್ಷ॒ ಶತೇ॑ಷುಧೇ ।
ನಿ॒ಶೀರ್ಯ॑ ಶ॒ಲ್ಯಾನಾಂ॒ ಮುಖಾ॑ ಶಿ॒ವೋ ನಃ॑ ಸು॒ಮನಾ॑ ಭವ ।
ವಿಜ್ಯಂ॒ ಧನುಃ॑ ಕಪ॒ರ್ದಿನೋ॒ ವಿಶ॑ಲ್ಯೋ॒ ಬಾಣ॑ವಾꣳ ಉ॒ತ ।
ಅನೇ॑ಶನ್ನ॒ಸ್ಯೇಷ॑ವ ಆ॒ಭುರ॑ಸ್ಯ ನಿಷಂ॒ಗಥಿಃ॑ । 
ಯಾ ತೇ॑ ಹೇ॒ತಿರ್ಮೀ॑ಢುಷ್ಟಮ॒ ಹಸ್ತೇ॑ ಬ॒ಭೂವ॑ ತೇ॒ ಧನುಃ॑ । 
ತಯಾ॒ಽಸ್ಮಾನ್, ವಿ॒ಶ್ವತ॒ಸ್ತ್ವಮ॑ಯ॒ಕ್ಷ್ಮಯಾ॒ ಪರಿ॑ಬ್ಭುಜ । 
ನಮ॑ಸ್ತೇ ಅ॒ಸ್ತ್ವಾಯು॑ಧಾ॒ಯಾನಾ॑ತತಾಯ ಧೃ॒ಷ್ಣವೇ᳚ । 
ಉ॒ಭಾಭ್ಯಾ॑ಮು॒ತ ತೇ॒ ನಮೋ॑ ಬಾ॒ಹುಭ್ಯಾಂ॒ ತವ॒ ಧನ್ವ॑ನೇ । 
ಪರಿ॑ ತೇ॒ ಧನ್ವ॑ನೋ ಹೇ॒ತಿರ॒ಸ್ಮಾನ್ವೃ॑ಣಕ್ತು ವಿ॒ಶ್ವತಃ॑ । 
ಅಥೋ॒ ಯ ಇ॑ಷು॒ಧಿಸ್ತವಾ॒ರೇ ಅ॒ಸ್ಮನ್ನಿಧೇ॑ಹಿ॒ ತಂ ॥ ೧ ॥ 
\end{document}
```

And I am attaching a picture where the hyphenation is not desired. Can I adjust spaces between words so that it looks nice in the document ?
I am using the command \! and ~ to adjust but I am not sure whether it is a good way to adjust.
[image]

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but the syntax `\Large{...}` is wrong. You should use `{\Large ...}`

Comment: Thanks will change

Comment: I answered you here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661346/alignment-and-hyphenation-issues/664996#664996